# iptables rules drop but pass anyway

Tags: iptables, firewall

I use these rules to restrict access at a server ssh from determinate ip:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i $DMZ_IFACE -p tcp ! -s 192.168.6.69 --dport 6724 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $LAN_IFACE -p tcp --sport 6724 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But i can access at port `6724` from any ip on `192.168.6.0/24`.

The firewall have 3 different ETH, for out, lan and dmz.

**EDIT:**
**This is the rules for NETWORK before the sshd rule:**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $DMZ_IFACE -d $DMZ_IP -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LAN_IFACE -d $LAN_IP -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LO_IFACE -s $LO_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LO_IFACE -s $LAN_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LO_IFACE -s $INET_IP -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -d $INET_IP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
-j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 194.168.6.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i $DMZ_IFACE -o $INET_IFACE -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i $INET_IFACE -o $DMZ_IFACE -m state \
--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i $LAN_IFACE -o $DMZ_IFACE -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i $DMZ_IFACE -o $LAN_IFACE -m state \
--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

**EDIT:**
**ETH config**

```
GO OUTSIDE  
    INET_IP="192.168.0.45"
    INET_IFACE="ens33"

LAN, HOST   
    LAN_IP="192.168.6.1"
    LAN_IP_RANGE="192.168.6.0/24"
    LAN_BROADCAST_ADDRESS="192.168.255.255"
    LAN_IFACE="ens39"

DMZ, SERVER WEB  
    DMZ_HTTP_IP="192.168.5.2"
    DMZ_IP="192.168.5.1"
    DMZ_IFACE="ens38"

    LO_IFACE="lo"
    LO_IP="127.0.0.1"
```

**EDIT:**
**iptables-save -c**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [141:12048]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:305]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:159]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_dmz - [0:0]
:POST_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:POST_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:POST_dmz_log - [0:0]
:POST_internal - [0:0]
:POST_internal_allow - [0:0]
:POST_internal_deny - [0:0]
:POST_internal_log - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_log - [0:0]
:PRE_internal - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.45/32 -i ens33 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.5.2:80
[2:146] -A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.45
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5604:557366]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1940:209203]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [98:7077]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [285:51551]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [378:58083]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_log - [0:0]
:PRE_internal - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
[6547:678748] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
[6547:678748] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
[6547:678748] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
[2291:261147] -A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
[98:7077] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
[381:68958] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
[474:75490] -A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
[1829:173183] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens38 -g PRE_dmz
[1879:176591] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens39 -g PRE_internal
[2202:256044] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens33 -g PRE_public
[34:3439] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
[1829:173183] -A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_log
[1829:173183] -A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_deny
[1829:173183] -A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_allow
[1879:176591] -A PRE_internal -j PRE_internal_log
[1879:176591] -A PRE_internal -j PRE_internal_deny
[1879:176591] -A PRE_internal -j PRE_internal_allow
[2836:328770] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
[2836:328770] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
[2836:328770] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5604:557366]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [285:51551]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_dmz_log - [0:0]
:PRE_internal - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_internal_log - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
[6547:678748] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
[6547:678748] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
[6547:678748] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
[381:68958] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
[1829:173183] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens38 -g PRE_dmz
[1879:176591] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens39 -g PRE_internal
[2202:256044] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens33 -g PRE_public
[34:3439] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
[1829:173183] -A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_log
[1829:173183] -A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_deny
[1829:173183] -A PRE_dmz -j PRE_dmz_allow
[1879:176591] -A PRE_internal -j PRE_internal_log
[1879:176591] -A PRE_internal -j PRE_internal_deny
[1879:176591] -A PRE_internal -j PRE_internal_allow
[602:46956] -A PRE_internal_allow -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j CT --helper netbios-ns
[2836:328770] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
[2836:328770] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
[2836:328770] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [700:101912]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [98:7077]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [372:67626]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
[701:101980] -A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
[98:7077] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
[373:68194] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
*filter
:INPUT DROP [50:4247]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [8:764]
:allowed - [0:0]
:bad_tcp_packets - [0:0]
:icmp_packets - [0:0]
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -j bad_tcp_packets
[0:0] -A INPUT -i ens33 -p icmp -j icmp_packets
[0:0] -A INPUT -d 192.168.5.1/32 -i ens38 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -d 192.168.6.1/32 -i ens39 -j ACCEPT
[8:636] -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 192.168.6.1/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.45/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -i ens39 -p udp -m udp --sport 68 --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[2:239] -A INPUT -d 192.168.0.45/32 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[4:284] -A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 3 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT INPUT packet died: " --log-level 7
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 194.168.6.0/24 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT ! -s 192.168.6.69/32 -i ens38 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6724 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
[0:0] -A FORWARD -p tcp -j bad_tcp_packets
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i ens39 -o ens38 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens39 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -d 192.168.5.2/32 -o ens38 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i ens39 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 3 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT FORWARD packet died: " --log-level 7
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -o ens39 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 6724 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j bad_tcp_packets
[8:636] -A OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.6.1/32 -j ACCEPT
[2:146] -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.45/32 -j ACCEPT
[3:322] -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 3 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT OUTPUT packet died: " --log-level 7
[0:0] -A allowed -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A allowed -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A allowed -p tcp -j DROP
[0:0] -A bad_tcp_packets -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
[0:0] -A bad_tcp_packets -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New not syn:"
[0:0] -A bad_tcp_packets -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP
[0:0] -A icmp_packets -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A icmp_packets -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 11 12:06:50 2020
```

**EDIT:**
**SCRIPT**

```
#!/bin/sh

###########################################################################
#
# 1. Configuration options.
#


INET_IP="192.168.0.45"
INET_IFACE="ens33"
#INET_BROADCAST="151.13.109.161"

LAN_IP="192.168.6.1"
LAN_IP_RANGE="192.168.6.0/24"
LAN_BROADCAST_ADDRESS="192.168.255.255"
LAN_IFACE="ens39"

#DMZ_HTTP_IP="192.168.1.2"
#DMZ_DNS_IP="192.168.1.3"
DMZ_HTTP_IP="192.168.5.2"
DMZ_IP="192.168.5.1"
DMZ_IFACE="ens38"

LO_IFACE="lo"
LO_IP="127.0.0.1"

###########################################################################
#
# 2. Module loading.
#

#
# Needed to initially load modules
#
/sbin/depmod -a



#
# 2.1 Required modules
#

/sbin/modprobe ip_tables
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack
/sbin/modprobe iptable_filter
/sbin/modprobe iptable_mangle
/sbin/modprobe iptable_nat
/sbin/modprobe ipt_LOG
/sbin/modprobe ipt_limit
/sbin/modprobe ipt_state

#
# 2.2 Non-Required modules
#

#/sbin/modprobe ipt_owner
#/sbin/modprobe ipt_REJECT
#/sbin/modprobe ipt_MASQUERADE
#/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
#/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_irc
#/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp
#/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_irc

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

echo " Loading iptables rules..."

#####################################
# Pulisco la configurazione corrente
#####################################

# Cancellazione delle regole presenti nelle chains
echo " Cancellazione delle regole presenti nelle chains"
iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat

# Eliminazione delle chains non standard vuote
echo " Eliminazione delle chains non standard vuote "
iptables -X

# Inizializzazione dei contatori (utile per il 7ging)
echo " Inizializzazione dei contatori (utile per il 7ging) "
iptables -Z

###########################################################################
#
# 4. rules set up.
#

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -N bad_tcp_packets
iptables -N allowed
iptables -N icmp_packets


iptables -A bad_tcp_packets -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK \
-m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

iptables -A bad_tcp_packets -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j LOG \
--log-prefix "New not syn:"

iptables -A bad_tcp_packets -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

#
# allowed chain
#

iptables -A allowed -p TCP --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A allowed -p TCP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A allowed -p TCP -j DROP

#
# ICMP rules
#

# Changed rules totally
iptables -A icmp_packets -p ICMP -s 0/0 --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
iptables -A icmp_packets -p ICMP -s 0/0 --icmp-type 11 -j DROP

#
# 4.1.4 INPUT chain
#
iptables -I INPUT -p ALL -d $INET_IP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j bad_tcp_packets

iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP -i $INET_IFACE -j icmp_packets

#
# Packets from LAN, DMZ or LOCALHOST
#

#
# From DMZ Interface to DMZ firewall IP
#

iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $DMZ_IFACE -d $DMZ_IP -j ACCEPT

#
# From LAN Interface to LAN firewall IP
#

iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LAN_IFACE -d $LAN_IP -j ACCEPT

#
# From Localhost interface to Localhost IP's
#

iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LO_IFACE -s $LO_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LO_IFACE -s $LAN_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $LO_IFACE -s $INET_IP -j ACCEPT

#
# Special rule for DHCP requests from LAN, which are not caught properly
# otherwise.
#

iptables -A INPUT -p UDP -i $LAN_IFACE --dport 67 --sport 68 -j ACCEPT

#
# All established and related packets incoming from the internet to the
# firewall
#

iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -d $INET_IP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
j ACCEPT

#
# Log weird packets that don't match the above.
#

iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/minute --limit-burst 3 -j LOG \
--log-level 7 --log-prefix "IPT INPUT packet died: "

#
# 4.1.5 FORWARD chain
#

#
# Bad TCP packets we don't want
#

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -j bad_tcp_packets
iptables -A INPUT -s 194.168.6.0/255.255.255.0 -j ACCEPT


#
# DMZ section
#
# General rules
#

iptables -A FORWARD -i $DMZ_IFACE -o $INET_IFACE -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INET_IFACE -o $DMZ_IFACE -m state \
--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $LAN_IFACE -o $DMZ_IFACE -m state \
--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $DMZ_IFACE -o $LAN_IFACE -m state \
--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

echo "SERVER WEB"
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i $INET_IFACE -d $INET_IP --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination $DMZ_HTTP_IP:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d $DMZ_HTTP_IP --dport 80 -o $DMZ_IFACE -j ACCEPT
#iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
echo "SERVER WEB OK"

echo "SERVER SSH"
iptables -A INPUT -i $DMZ_IFACE -p tcp -m tcp ! -s 192.168.6.69 -d $DMZ_HTTP_IP --dport 6724 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i $INET_IFACE -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.0.2 -d $INET_IP --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 22,6724 -j DROP


#
# LAN section
#

iptables -A FORWARD -i $LAN_IFACE -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#
# Log weird packets that don't match the above.
#

iptables -A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/minute --limit-burst 3 -j LOG \
--log-level 7 --log-prefix "IPT FORWARD packet died: "

#
# 4.1.6 OUTPUT chain
#

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j bad_tcp_packets

iptables -A OUTPUT -p ALL -s $LO_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p ALL -s $LAN_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p ALL -s $INET_IP -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/minute --limit-burst 3 -j LOG \
--log-level 7 --log-prefix "IPT OUTPUT packet died: "


#
# Enable simple IP Forwarding and Network Address Translation
#

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INET_IFACE -j SNAT --to-source $INET_IP
```

Comment: is you sshd binded to all interfaces? the rule above seem to only restrict the connect if it is directed to the DMZ interface.

Comment: Hi, see edit in my post, i add network rules info. thanks

Comment: Please use `iptables-save -c` to list the full ruleset and paste it into the post.

Comment: We don't know the values of your variables like `$INET_IP` and `$LAN_IP`. I can see many `ACCEPT` rules. Are you adding your `DROP` rule after all of these?

Comment: see my last edit on my post.

Comment: @AntonDanilov  see my edit in post, thanks

Comment: @Khaled see my edit in post

Comment: Where have you these rules configured? On the server itself or on the gateway?

Comment: @AntonDanilov in a linux firewall/gateway 3 eth (public,intranet, dmz)

Comment: @AntonDanilov hi Anton, i edit my post and public the script, can you take a look? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following (at least):

1. Are these the only rules in your firewall ruleset? You may have other allowing rule(s) before the `DROP` one.
2. Are you sure the traffic is coming through interface `DMZ_IFACE`?

Comment: see edit in my post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this just check the rule counters in `iptables-save -c` output. I think your restriction rule has zero counters. That means there is some rule accepts the packets earlier.

When you had added your restriction rule with `iptables -A INPUT` command, this rule was placed at the end of chains.

To achieve your goal you should place your DROP rules at the right position. But best way is create separate chain of rules.

Also, your `DROP` rule blocks only new connections, but if you already has established connection, it will be alive.

Comment: Thanks Anton for your answer, can you take a look please at the script i put in my last edit in my post?